# MySQL - Fetching all posts added to all subcategories linked to a parent category

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called Categories. I also have another table called blog.
For example, a parent category called "technology" has been added to the categories table. Added "computer" and "cars" as subcategories

If the selected category is "technology", I want to bring it and all the articles added to the subcategories "cars" and "computer". If "computer" is selected, the same process will be done, but if not, it will not bring it.

How can I do all this in a short query?

I want to adapt this to the following code

`$pullData = $database_class->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM blog WHERE categories = ? AND status = ? AND title LIKE ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ' . $whereCheck . ', ' . $maxColumn . ''); $pullData->execute([$category_data["id"], 1, "%".$q."%"]); $blogPosts = $pullData->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Writing a MySQL query.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pullData = $database_class->db->prepare('
    SELECT *
    FROM blog
    WHERE categories IN (
        SELECT id
        FROM categories
        WHERE parent_category_id = ? OR id = ?
    )
    AND status = ?
    AND title LIKE ?
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT ?, ?;
');

$pullData->execute([$category_data["id"], $category_data["id"], 1, "%".$q."%", $whereCheck, $maxColumn]);
$blogPosts = $pullData->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Can you adapt this to count? I couldn't do it, it didn't work. It returns 0 data in the count section.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).